# use ActionChains in a loop

Tags: python, selenium

On a webpage there's an element('map') that by clicking on it a text appears inside a 'x' element. 
In a for loop I'm using ActionChains to click on 'map' each time and then get the text inside 'x'. But at some iterations browser.find_element_by_id('x').text returns an empty string and sometimes it returns the correct text. It seems before the action is performed it's executing the next line. Is it possible? what can the problem be?

Here is the code:

```
mylist = []
for i in range(4):
    map = browser.find_element_by_id('map')
    action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(browser)
    action.move_to_element(mapcanvas).click().perform()
    txt = browser.find_element_by_id('x').text
    mylist.append(txt)
```

Comment: If clicking is performing some action, it may be that the page doesn't immediately update. You may need to add a wait or even a custom wait to make sure that your X element gets updated before checking the text. It's hard to say exactly without more information or a link to the page.